# jQuery change the value of a variable on dropdown select from database

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I am working on a project where I am stuck at a point right now. I need to change the value of a DIV live on select of the dropdown using jQuery.

Example:

I want this:-

```
<select name="">
<option value="10">10 clicks</option>
<option value="20">20 clicks</option>
<option value="30">30 clicks</option>
<option value="40">40 clicks</option>
</select>

<div id="chpln">Clicks: 0 clicks</div>
```

When I will select option 1 the value will be displayed in place of 0 in DIV live. The problem is that as this select value fetches data from the database I am not understanding how to do it.

Example:

```
<select name="" id="pln" class="select-box" style="margin-top: -40px;"  />
  <?php while($ac_fetch = mysql_fetch_array($qur_ac)){ ?>
  <option value="<?php echo $ac_fetch['adclk_clicks']; ?>"><?php echo $ac_fetch['adclk_clicks']; ?> clicks</option>
  <?php } ?>
</select>
```

jQuery that I used currently:-

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#pln").click(function(){
        $("#chpln").text("Plan: <?php echo $ac_fetch['adclk_clicks']; ?> secs");
    });
});
```

This jquery is changing the value currently but I am getting only the first value of the database i.e., 10. When I choose different option it still displays the first value from the database i.e., 10 while it should actually display the second value that is 20. Please help me. FIDDLE will be appreciated.

Comment: you can do that by creating a php file to fetch data from database and call that file using ajax from jquery then update your view with the response returned in ajax

Comment: can u give a code example for clearing the concept?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

click is a wrong event for selection box
you can utilize change event for your result.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#pln").change(function(){
        $("#chpln").text("Plan: "+$(this).val()+" secs");
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks bro.. This was exactly what I was actually looking for.. Thanks alot.. :)

Comment: Such a nice & clean example. thumbs up @ameenulla

Answer (score 0):

For Dropdown, `click(function()` is not applicable. Use `change(function()`.

I gave you 2 way. Use any one.

**I) Method - 1** (Using Ajax)

```
<select name="" id="pln" class="select-box" style="margin-top: -40px;"  />
  <?php while($ac_fetch = mysql_fetch_array($qur_ac)){ ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $ac_fetch['adclk_clicks']; ?>">
        <?php echo $ac_fetch['adclk_clicks']; ?> clicks
    </option>
  <?php } ?>
</select>

<div id="chpln">Clicks: 0 clicks</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $('.select-box').change(function(){
       var selectBoxClicks = $('.select-box').val();
       $.ajax({url:"AjaxShowClickValue.php?selectBoxClicks="+selectBoxClicks,cache:false,success:function(result){
         $('#chpln').html(result);
       }});
  });
</script>
```

Create a new page, namely **AjaxShowClickValue.php**.

**AjaxShowClickValue.php** (Make Sure, if you changing page name here. Then, change in `<script></script>` tag too. Both are related.)

```
<?
echo "Clicks: ".$_GET['selectBoxClicks']." clicks";
?>
```

**II) Method - 2**

```
<select name="" class='select-box'>
    <option value="10">10 clicks</option>
    <option value="20">20 clicks</option>
    <option value="30">30 clicks</option>
    <option value="40">40 clicks</option>
</select>

<div id="chpln">Clicks: 0 clicks</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $('.select-box').change(function(){
         $("#chpln").text("Clicks: "+$(this).val()+" clicks");
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks Nana PartyKar (a good mimic of Nana Patekar)... Thanks for giving your time.. Main try to nahi kar paya apka code bcoz ameenulla007's answer did the job. However I will keep your method for any future references. Thanks for taking out your time for me and yes.... Jai Hind :)

Comment: Jai Hind @ShubhamJha. *Achha Hain.. Bahut Achha Hain..*

Comment: Nana sahab ki hasi to banti hai.... Par text me nahi ho sakta... Main thori bohot mimicry kar leta hu.. Would u mind if we connect? Here is my whatsapp number 9832462710... Acha hai.. Bahut acha hai... :)

Answer (score 0):

use [jQuery Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) for making request to the php file..

and use on [`.change()`](https://api.jquery.com/change/) rather than `.click()` for changing the dropdown value..

the code will be placed in JS file which make ajax call to the php file on your server..

The php file will takes some params (if any) and perform select query to the databases and return result in response.. in php use `json_encode(data)` for that..

These examples may also help: 
http://www.plus2net.com/php_tutorial/ajax_drop_down_list.php
http://www.plus2net.com/php_tutorial/php_drop_down_list.php

You will find many other examples - Just Google It and understand the key concept!

Hope this helps.